# How do I override arguments in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I could would like to have multiple interfaces for my class.

Example:

```js
type OAuthCliStrategyOpts = {
  oauthStrategy: express.Handler;
  oauthStrategyOptions: object;
  appKey: string;
  appSecret: string;
};

type OAuthCliDefaultOpts = {
  authorizationURL: string;
  tokenURL: string;
  appKey: string;
  appSecret: string;

  callbackURL?: string;
};

type OAuthCliOpts = OAuthCliDefaultOpts | OAuthCliStrategyOpts;
```

But when I try to specify:

```js
oauthCLI({
        oauthStrategy: DropboxOAuth2Strategy,
        oauthStrategyOptions: {
          apiVersion: "2"
        },
        appSecret: "KEY",
        appKey: "SECRET"
      })
```

I get an error:

````
Argument of type '{ oauthStrategy: any; oauthStrategyOptions: { apiVersion: string; }; appSecret: string; appKey: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OAuthCliOpts'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'oauthStrategy' does not exist in type 'OAuthCliOpts'.

    146         oauthStrategy: DropboxOAuth2Strategy,
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ```
````

Comment: Compiles fine for me. Do you have a complete snippet?

Comment: Also, those are not interfaces, they're type aliases.

Comment: Please consider editing the above code to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) to demonstrate your issue.  Right now I cannot reproduce your problem with the code, so it's hard to know what to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

oauthCLI({
        oauthStrategy: DropboxOAuth2Strategy,
        oauthStrategyOptions: {
          apiVersion: "2"
        },
        appSecret: "KEY",
        appKey: "SECRET"
      } as OAuthCliStrategyOpts )

Comment: That's just a way to tell the compiler: "Don't worry, it looks wrong, but I know what I'm doing." You can make any error disappear with that approach.